# Transferring solana to a hardcoded publickey

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang

```
  let fee_pubkey_str = "auth8dV96CVJrsFxAdDM13eo1fFq9vE27C2EJ2yezJw"; 

    let fee_pubkey = Pubkey::from_str(fee_pubkey_str).unwrap();

    let transfer_to_fee = solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
        &ctx.accounts.player.key(),
        &fee_pubkey,
        ctx.accounts.game_match.commission_amount,
    );
    solana_program::program::invoke(
        &transfer_to_fee,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.player.to_account_info(),
            // Add fee account_info()
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;
```

output: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing

How can I add fee account info? All I want to do is to provide a fee flow to the public wallet, which I define as hardcode.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in the account you want to transfer the funds to in your `Accounts` struct and use that in the transfer instruction.

Using the transfer instruction from `anchor` would look like this

```
    use anchor_lang::system_program::Transfer

    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from,
        to,
    };
    let cpi_program = system_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    system_program::transfer(cpi_context, fees).expect("Insufficient Funds");
```

Becuase of how Solana processes instructions, you need to tell it beforehand the accounts it will interact with and as such passing in a public key is not currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

The account is missing since you've only provided the address within the instruction logic. You'll need to include the fee_pubkey as one of the accounts required by the instruction instead of hardcoding the address.

Here is an example you can reference for how to create an instruction for a SOL transfer.

https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/basics/transfer-sol/anchor/programs/transfer-sol/src/lib.rs